# Order names in relation to their score

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Beginner here. So I have a column with the names of people and another one with their score. I want to have a third column where their names are in order of their score (with the best one at the top). Is it possible to do that? If so how?

Here is the file you can tinker with it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mP1eVpRnS3BIEMI2rH6OT1oeABlfFpBK95QV-9Baz70/edit#gid=0

Comment: the file is readonly

Comment: sorry it's good now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

`query($A$2:$B$13;"select A order by B desc")`

Enter the formula in cell C2, it will automatically populate the rows below.

Answer (score 0):

paste in **E1** cell:

```
={"ranking"; QUERY(A2:B; "select A order by B desc")}
```

[image: 0]